# Help identify slightly-adult 80s/90s trilogy - set on Earth with magic/aliens/mushrooms/familiars

Tags: story-identification, witches

Wasn't the greatest, but I never finished it!
Here's what I remember:

- Male author
- Male protagonist
- Female villain - Erzsebet
- Old mage-type
- Rat-like Familiars eating people - Jamara and Pyewacket
- Dog like Familiar - Glebula / clod of earth
- Destroying Angel - Amanita mushrooms
- Aliens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be "[The Destroying Angel](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/bernard-king-2/destroying-angel-vol-i-of-the-chronicles-of-the/)" by Bernard King? The [book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EJ2BvOQUf0oC&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=destroying%20angel%20bernard%20king&source=bl&ots=koxF1POWRv&sig=ERvrt3YP6Q34GeR6O_PewfSUxkE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fi_MU4zHL-fG7AbLgYHABg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=destroying%20angel%20bernard%20king&f=false) seems to tickle a fair few of the points you've mentioned:

- Male author
- 1980s publishing date
- Adult theming (grisly murders, etc)
- Male protagonist
- Part of a [Trilogy of books](http://www.sfbooklist.co.uk/authorsk.html)
- Heavy mushroom theme (title is obviously a species of mushroom)
- Pyewacket is named as a character
- Mention of various witches' familiars not being cats but "rodent-like" creatures that feed on blood.

[image]

Comment: That's the one - thank you!

Comment: @astra - Glad to help; http://media2.giphy.com/media/oNlovU1bJOcYE/giphy.gif